# Hadoop - Struggling with First Time Setup

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop on my Windows 7 machine.  I'm doing this for the first time ever, and following the instructions here.

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

I went through everything and customized my setup to look like the steps outlined below.

I executed and installed Java, from the folder below:

```
C:\Java\jdk-8u201-windows-x64.exe
```

I have all Hadoop folders and files, here:

```
C:\Hadoop\
```

[image]

I have modified the following files in the the manner displayed below:

```
hadoop-env.sh

set JAVA_Home=C:\Java

set HADOOP_PREFIX=C:\Hadoop\
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_PREFIX%
set YARN_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%
set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin
```

#

```
core-site.xml:

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:19000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#

```
hdfs-site.xml:

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

mapred-site.xml:

<configuration>

   <property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.user.name</name>
     <value>%USERNAME%</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
     <value>yarn</value>
   </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.apps.stagingDir</name>
    <value>/user/%USERNAME%/staging</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>local</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

#

```
yaml-site.xml:

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:8020</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.resourcemanager.application.expiry.interval</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.nodemanager.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:45454</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/app-logs</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/dep/logs/userlogs</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.mapreduce-appmanager.attempt-listener.bindAddress</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.mapreduce-appmanager.client-service.bindAddress</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>-1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%,%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*,%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*,%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

#

```
slaves:

master
slave
localhost
```

Now, this should be pretty close to the setup recommended in the link I posted, but something is off somewhere, because I can't get Hadoop to startup and display the localhost web page.  Can someone see something missing?  I'd love to get this working sooner or later!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.  You need to follow the instructions as described in the link that I posted.  in addition, you need to make sure all Java dependencies are updated.  Download and run the following 2 executables:

```
jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
jdk-8u201-windows-x64.exe
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

Finally, download two files (`hadoop.dll & winutils.exe`) and place them in the follwing folder.

```
C:\Hadoop\bin\
```

The two files can be found from the link below:

```
https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin
```

Download both files and put them in the following folder: